# usb storage attached to windows SBS is not readable when plugged directly to windows desktop

Tags: storage, usb

I was wondering if windows SBS did some sort of different format other than ntfs that would make my usb storage (16tb drobo) readable only to the server

If I unplug the usb and take it over to my win 7 laptop I get a "this disk needs to be formated" prompt, but when I plug it back into the server its perfectly fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this a USB drive that has been configured for Windows backups on the server? If so, that's probably what your problem is.

Comment: no its not for backup its where i have all the network share folders.